# Where can I get the Node.js shared libraries under macOS?

Tags: c++, node.js, macos

I want to test [embedding Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/embedding.html) code inside a C++ application, as shown in this [official example](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/22907ce3668b69543acb07f293817f092e03a267/test/embedding/embedtest.cc). Under Linux, this requires installing Node.js and running something like:

```
g++ -I/usr/include/node -luv -lnode main.cpp
```

to compile the application, which links dynamically against Node.

However, I cannot get this to work under macOS, simply because I cannot locate a `libnode.dylib` file that would be required for this. I have installations of Node.js through Homebrew (`brew install node`) and NVM, and neither of them seems to provide a shared library. For example, I can locate `libuv.dylib` using:

```
➜ find /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ -name '*.dylib' | grep uv
/opt/homebrew/Cellar//libuv/1.46.0/lib/libuv.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar//libuv/1.46.0/lib/libuv.1.dylib
```

But there is nothing searching for `node`. Similar for `~/.nvm/versions/node/v20.0.0/lib` which contains no `.dylib` files.

Where would one find shared libraries for Node under macOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Node.js only ships a `node` binary to execute Node code. Distributions *may* supply shared libs, which is the case for Ubuntu, for example. See the [`BUILDING.md` file](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/BUILDING.md#building-to-use-shared-dependencies-at-runtime):

> By default Node.js is built so that all dependencies are bundled into the Node.js binary itself. This provides a single binary that includes the correct versions of all dependencies on which it depends.

> Some Node.js distributions, however, prefer to manage dependencies. A number of configure options are provided to support this use case.

Mind you that the `libnode-dev` version may lag behind the official Node LTS.

There is a way to build a shared library from source, by downloading the source code and configuring it using `./configure --shared`.